# Percentage per user of total - reach best perfomance

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get a percentage of items/user in our warehouse (only items which are out of stock).

```
item_id |  partner_id  | item_name  | stock_sum       |   manager_id   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------     
23020   |  232         |  cola      |        0        |      237             
39935   |  232         |  sprite    |        0        |       89      
23030   |  232         |  fanta     |        60       |       32    
15331   |  232         |  water     |        20       |      237
```

So i have to get:

manager_id = 237    -> 0,25 -> 25%

manager_id = 89     -> 0,25 -> 25%

total               -> 0,50 -> 50%

My first idea was something like this:

```
select skk.manger_id, count(*), count(skk.item_id/sk.item_id) as prcntg
from stock skk
  inner join stock sk on skk.item_id = sk.item_id and skk.manager_id = sk.manager_id 
where skk.stock_sum = 0
group by skk.manager_id
```

But i think this is not the right solution.. so i need help.

[Output] expected:

```
manager_id  |  total |  %  of total (prcntg)
----------------------------------------------
 237        |   0,5  |  0,25
  89        |   0,5  |  0,25 
  32        |   0,5  |     0
```

Comment: `count()` counts non-null values and returns an integer value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be describing this a calculation using window functions:

```
select manager_id, count(*) as num_items,
       sum(case when stock_sum = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as num_out_of_stock,
       avg(case when stock_sum = 0 then 1.0 else 0 end) as manager_avg,
       sum(case when stock_sum = 0 then 1 else 0 end) / count(*) as overall_avg
from stock s
group by manager_id;
```

The `overall_avg` is what you seem to be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
select manager_id, sum(av) pcnt
  from (
    select manager_id, count(case stock_sum when 0 then 1 end) / sum(count(1)) over () as av
      from stock group by manager_id)
  group by rollup(manager_id)
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b52fdcd481937f01792a7e3ed4734e6d)</sup>**

Divide counted zeros by number of all entries (analytical sum of all counts). Use outer rollup if you need total value.